# How to run docker cointainer from kylemanna/docker-bitcoind on testnet

Tags: bitcoind

I have a `bitcoin.conf`.
It looks like this:

```
testnet=1
server=1
rpcuser=Ulysseys
rpcpassword=YourrrPassword
rpctimeout=30
rpcport=8332
```

Now I try to run a container from this [image](https://github.com/kylemanna/docker-bitcoind):

Create volume:

```
$ docker volume create --name=bitcoind-data
```

Create container:

```
docker run -v bitcoind-data:/bitcoin --name=bitcoind-node -d \
        -p 8333:8333 \
        -p 127.0.0.1:8332:8332 \
        -v /path/to/bitcoin.conf:/bitcoin/.bitcoin/bitcoin.conf \
        kylemanna/bitcoind -testnet
```

I go inside my container and check with `bitcoin-cli getinfo`:

```
{
  "version": 140200,
  "protocolversion": 70015,
  "walletversion": 130000,
  "balance": 0.00000000,
  "blocks": 0,
  "timeoffset": 0,
  "connections": 0,
  "proxy": "",
  "difficulty": 1,
  "testnet": true,
  "keypoololdest": 1503649077,
  "keypoolsize": 100,
  "paytxfee": 0.00000000,
  "relayfee": 0.00001000,
  "errors": ""
}
```

Testnet=true so that's okay but I don't see any log of data (`docker logs container-name`). Also my docker volume is still 17MB and 0 blocks.

What am I doing wrong?

When I load my `bitcoin.conf` in my `bitcoin-qt` on macosx it becomes green but remains on 'pending' to get the blockchain.

Is there something wrong with my config or is it maybe blocked on my network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `printtoconsole=1` to you bitcoin.conf will activate log output to the console. With this `docker logs container` will show the log.

Comment: Thanks, it was my networking which was locking it. Wich port do I need to open? 8332 or 18332, 8333 or 18333?